# What is the File Socket Limit CentOS 6(Web Server)

Tags: centos6

I would like some brief explanation on the file socket limit in CentOS 6.

I have try google and did not find alot of information.

What is it?
What is the default size?
Is it enough for a general web server?
How to change the default size?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following:

```
ulimit -a
man ulimit
```